# Row Selection on tr:table not clearing on page refresh

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, myfaces, trinidad

I am using MyFaces 2.1.17 and Trinidad 2.1 in my application. I have a page with tr:table which has rowSelection as "single" defined on it. When i select the radio button against a record and then refresh / re-navigate to the same page, the row selection should be discarded and the table should be displayed without any selection on it. This was working fine when I used Trinidad 1.2. But when I upgraded to Trinidad 2.1 & MyFaces 2.1.17, the rowSelection is retained even after page refresh. I believe the rowSelection is being stored in the cache and applied to the table on renderResponse phase.

I tried clearing the selectedRowKeys and setting the rowIndex to -1 when navigating to the page but still the selection is retained.

Can someone help me with the below questions ?
1. Where do the rowSelection gets stored in Trinidad - browser chache or managed bean ?
2. How can we clear the rowSelection using javascript ?
3. Is this something new with JSF 2 ?

Comment: Maybe you are now using view scope for the backbean? Older versions of JSF have not view scope, and if you were using request scope you can notice this new behavior.

Comment: @malaguna - My managed bean is in session scope...